# jQuery Cross Domain Iframe Height Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have the following javascript that determines the content height of an iframe:

```
var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement;
var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
```

First time, this works great! Once i have the height i post it to the parent page, like so:

```
parent.postMessage(height, '*');
```

On the parent page i listen for the post message event and set the height of the iframe, like so:

```
$('#frame').height(data);
```

So far so good! Now when the iframe navigates within it self to a different page and it recalculates the content height, it keeps returning the height it calculated the first time.

I am assuming that this is because the iframe now has an explicit height. How do i ensure that i get the actual content height and not the height set on the iframe?

Comment: Can you provide a working example of your issue? Or at least a jsfiddle?

Comment: Maybe, get the height of a container in the body?

Comment: do the other pages you're navigating to have a doctype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin B for the tip.

Replaced:

```
var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement;
var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
```

With:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].offsetHeight
```

Works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute the **body height** on document.ready.

I suggest you to use [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) to get some fallback on postMessage. [easyXDM has an example exactly about getting an iframe height](http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/resize-iframe-based-on-content/).